# Run Javascript when span is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say i have got this code :

```
<span anyattribute="alert(1)"></span>
```

Is it possible to run Javascript code when span element loads on page only using attributes (events such as onload, onerror etc.)?

Comment: Define "loaded". Only elements like images, iframes, scripts, stylesheets have the "onload", for span it's always loaded as soon as the node is added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

If by "loaded" you mean when the span is added to the DOM, you have only two options for triggering JavaScript code when that happens:

1. Using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the element it gets added to (or an ancestor of it) and then checking to see if the mutation involved adding that span, or
2. Polling to check for the existence of the element.

Both have advantages and disadvantages depending on your situation.